# How to make direction to filename to read it from IDLE?

Tags: python-3.x, filenames, direction

If i have a filename in this direction in my laptop:

```
F:\python\python filenames
```

which named `test.txt`
And if My program direction is:

```
C:\Users\Msi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36
```

which named `fib.py`

---

How can i read or make change to my filename without copying it beside my program `fib.py`? I must write the direction of my filename in my program file?? How can i do that to above example?
I tried this:`filename='F:\python\python filenames\test.txt'` in my program
But it didn't work!Error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'F:\\python\\python filenames\test.txt'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway I found the solution:

```
filename='F:\\python\\python filenames\\test.txt'
```

it works!